# Storefront Child Theme show product attribute

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i'm building a child theme for storefront, how to display the attributes of a product on list product page other than the product name and price?

example this list only show product name and price, i want show "desc" or "size" here :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to code externally for that. Please refer the screenshots given below:

[image: Add product attributes from the dashboard]

Add product attributes from the dashboard as shown in the above image.

[image: Attributes will be shown under Additional Information]

At the front end product attributes will be shown under the section *Additional Information*.

Hope your problem is solved, if not please post a comment below.

**Answer for updated question:**

Since you want to show product attributes on product list page, just add following lines in your functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_attr');

function show_attr()
{
    global $product;
    $product->list_attributes();
}
```

Product list page will look like this:

[image: Product attributes will look like this]

Comment: Sorry, i have edited my question, i want to show it on the products list page, not product single

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Also [the plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-show-attributes/) might help you.

Comment: Thank you for updated the answer! this is what i need! thank you so much!